# Watson Assistant - context variable as node condition

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am trying to create a variation on my welcome node which will advise user if their Active Directory(AD) password is due to expire in next 30 days, and if it is to show how many days until it expires.

I have a context variable for PasswordExpiry coming from AD. Can i use context variable as a condition for the node - ie if bot recognizes xxx?

How can i get it to display number of days between today & password expiry date?

my welcome node currently has this:

```
context.passwordExpires &&
context.passwordExpires.minusDays(30) < now() 
? 'Your login password is due to expire on ' +
context.passwordExpires.reformatDateTime('MMMM d, yyyy') +
' at ' + 
context.passwordExpires.reformatDateTime('h:mm a') + 
', which is within 30 days. Please change it now!' 
: 'not 30'
```

This code works, but i want to use outcomes of this to jump to different nodes - so if less than 30 days goes to a particlaur welcome answer with options, and over 30 goes to another welcome reponse with options.

Ideally i also want to be able to say your password expires in `xxx` number of days.

I have tried to make the contect variable a condition for the node so like this `context.passwordExpires.minusDays(60)` but i cant get this to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, you can. What exactly is your question? Please provide details, what you tried, what did not work, what is the real issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `java.util.Date.getTime()` function to return the dates in milliseconds. Then divide the result to get the number of days.

More details in documentation here:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-java-util-date

Comment: will add example code later if no one else does.

Comment: thanks Simon - will check that out